# how to work out endpoints in a client authorization app, okta, oidc .net

Tags: openid-connect, endpoint, okta

After playing with oidc authentication to understand it better. I know where I am failing, I am not setting up the endpoints correctly. So I have downloaded some code and play a little bit with it.

What I want to do is change the redirecturls for login and logout. This code is meant to allow me to connect through an external server (okta):
in startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            })
            .AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
           .AddCookie()
           .AddOktaMvc(new OktaMvcOptions
           {
                // Replace these values with your Okta configuration
               OktaDomain = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:OktaDomain"),
               AuthorizationServerId = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:AuthorizationServerId"),
               ClientId = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:ClientId"),
               ClientSecret = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:ClientSecret"),
               Scope = new List<string> { "openid", "profile", "email" },
           });

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

In the readme files, it specifies that in order to make it work, I have to update the endpoints on okta, which I've done, setting them up to .../authorization-code/callback for login and ../signout/callback for logout.

So I looked at the code, and authorization-code is not a controller, and either signout.

This is my home controller:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult SignIn()
        {
            if (!HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return Challenge(OktaDefaults.MvcAuthenticationScheme);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SignOut()
        {
            return new SignOutResult(
                new[]
                {
                     OktaDefaults.MvcAuthenticationScheme,
                     CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                },
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/Home/" });
        }
```

So, can someone explain me the endpoints on my end, please? I don't see a callback, or an authorization-code, but I do see a signout, but not with a callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it!!!

The problem was that it is set by default, in the nuget package that is downloaded, there is a class to set up the default values as per screenshot:

[image: Okta defaults]

then to change this, I only have to change the values of this, or set up a different values. Thanks everyone for reading, I hope this can help somebody else